# Algolia android instant search on query change not working

Tags: android, algolia, instantsearch-android

I am exploring the Algolia search suggestion, I am facing an issue that the search suggestion adapter is not getting refreshed when I start typing it keeps on showing the same suggestion, It should show the matching suggestion because I already connected the search view, Is there any extra thing I need to do I followed your documentation regarding Algolia search suggestion

[Algolia Search Suggestion For Android](https://www.algolia.com/doc/guides/building-search-ui/ui-and-ux-patterns/query-suggestions/tutorials/building-query-suggestions-ui/android/)

I think the query change listener is conflicting, check the code snippet below

**Approach 1 Not Working**

```
searchView.setOnQueryTextFocusChangeListener { _, hasFocus ->
        showSuggestions()
        showProducts()
    }
```

**Approach 2 Not Working**

```
searchView.setOnQueryTextListener(object : SearchView.OnQueryTextListener {
        override fun onQueryTextSubmit(query: String?): Boolean {
            return true
        }

        override fun onQueryTextChange(newText: String?): Boolean {
            showSuggestions()
            showProducts()
            return true
        }

    })
```

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you are calling both `showSuggestions()` and `showProducts()` methods same time, which could lead to the issue,

Can you try to modify the code as here and see?

```
searchView.setOnQueryTextFocusChangeListener { _, hasFocus ->
    if (hasFocus) showSuggestions() else showProducts()
}
```

Also, make sure to use the `setReorderingAllowed(true)` method inside the `showSuggestions()` and `showProducts()` methods.